# Как сделать так, чтобы высота псевдоэлемента была как у его content, а не как у родительского блока и расположить его по центру

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование

```html
<a>
  Hello
  <img src="a.svg">
</a>
```

```css
a{
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
}
a::before {
 content: url("a.svg");
}
```

[image: _Hello-]

Почему ::before все так же останется внизу и при этом у него высота равна высоте всего контейнера, а img будет по центру и его высота будет 2px как само изображение? Как расположить псведоэлемент так же и желательно без позиционирования?

Comment: что у Вас представляет собой `a.svg`? линию перед Hello? а вторая линия после Hello откуда? что такое "img будет по центру и его высота будет 2px как само изображение"?

Comment: поправил код, img - линия будет по центру как справа на фотографии, а сейчас оно как слева на фотографии

Comment: сделайте просто два img по бокам от Hello. в чём логика справа вставлять картинку через img, а слева её же - через псевдоэлемент?

Comment: так это просто пример как должно быть, вот с картинкой получилось, а мне нужно, чтобы с псевдоэлементом так же вышло

Comment: img лучше не использовать для такого (разве что для примера) before & after, просто попробуйте у них подрегулировать background-position: 50% 50% например…

Comment: добавь содержимое `a.svg` тоже

Answer (score -1):

Вот пример, я конечно рекомендовал бы сделать линии не по центру, а чуть ниже на 1-2px

```css
.wrapper {
  display:flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

a{
  position: relative;
}

a::after,
a::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 1px;  
  top: 50%;
  background-color: red;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

a::after {  
  right: 0;
  transform: translateX(100%);
}

a::before {
  left: 0;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<a>Hello</a>
<div>
```

Comment: Wrapper не влияет на позиционирование псевдоэлементов.  Добавил только для красоты вывода ответа.